# Get coordinates of touch event relative to Image

Tags: react-native

I have an image centered on the screen. I need to make it touchable and I need to get the coordinates of the touch event relative to the image. I have wrapped my image in a TouchableOpacity to make it touchable. The problem is that the touch coordinates are relative to the TouchableOpacity and not the Image. The TouchableOpacity is taking up the entire screen but the Image is centered inside it.

I either need to make my TouchableOpacity the same size as the Image, or I need to know the offset of the Image within the TouchableOpacity.

I have tried using OnLayout and the NativeEvent object to get the position of the Image within it's parent but it just returns 0,0.

```
    const {width, height} = Dimensions.get("window");

    class Inspection extends React.Component {

        handlePress(evt) {
            // do stuff
            ...
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <View style={{flex:1, backgroundColor:'#fff'}}>
                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        onPress={(evt) => this.handlePress(evt)}
                        style={{backgroundColor: '#3897f0'}}
                    >
                        <Image 
                            onLayout={({nativeEvent}) => {
                                console.log(nativeEvent.layout);
                            }}
                            source={require('../../images/wireframe-car.jpg')}
                            resizeMode='contain'
                            style={{
                                maxHeight: height,
                                maxWidth: width
                                }} 
                        />
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

Console Output:

```
{height: 683.4285888671875, width: 411.4285583496094, y: 0, x: 0}
```

I've added a backgroundColor to TouchableOpacity so you can see that it takes up the entire screen.

[image: Screenshot]

Is there another way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TouchableOpacity** would be the same size as of the **Image** because you haven't given any height to it, you simply need to assign **onLayout** prop to your TouchableOpacity like this

```
      <View
        style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#fff', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => {
            console.log(nativeEvent.layout)
          }}
          style={{}}
          onPress={evt => this.handlePress(evt)}>
          <Image
            source={require('../../images/wireframe-car.jpg')}
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={{
              maxWidth: '100%',
            }}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
```

This will give you the exact x and y of Image.

**Update**

The problem is also with image size, since the image size is quite big so it takes the height of the device and we get x:0 and y:0, in order to resolve this issue we can give the Image component a static height or calculate its height according to width. We can get width and height image from local path like this:

```
let imageUri = Image.resolveAssetSource(require('../../images/wireframe-car.jpg').uri)
    Image.getSize(imageUri , (width, height) => { 
    console.log(`The image dimensions are ${width}x${height}`); 
    }, (error) => { 
    console.error(`Couldn't get the image size: ${error.message}`); 
    });
```

Comment: I've moved my onLayout prop to the TouchableOpacity and made the other changes but it still gives me 0,0 as the x,y coordinates. I've added a background color to the TouchableOpacity and uploaded a screenshot so you can see it.

Comment: what is the height and width of the image?

Comment: The image is 1496 x 974 but I have it scaled to fit whatever the screen size is.

Comment: is this what you are doing Dimensions.get('window').width

Comment: the problem is with image size, image of this size will take all the screen height and width,  that is why its x:0, y:0

Comment: either don't set maxHeight to Dimensions.get('window').height and set some static value like 100 or remove maxHeight will resolve the issue.

Comment: The image does not take all of screen height and width. As you can see in the screenshot there is blue area above the image so the image position is not (0,0). What I'm trying to find is the amount of blue area above the image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181494/discussion-between-haider-ali-and-kent).

Comment: Hey man since the issue is solved can you also upvote and accept the answer. thanks